# Unable to create a client-server connection in ignite

Tags: spring, caching, ignite

I have successfully created a connection between client and server(localhost) in ignite.But while trying to connect the ignite server which is running in remote IP(eg: 192.168.33.44), I am not able to establish connection. The client side configuration given below.

```
@Bean(name = "igniteConfiguration")
public IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration() {
    IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
    igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(true);
    igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
    igniteConfiguration.setLocalHost("127.0.0.1");
    TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
    ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPort(47500);
    // Changing local port range. This is an optional action.
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPortRange(9);
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalAddress("localhost");
    igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);
    TcpCommunicationSpi communicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
    communicationSpi.setLocalAddress("localhost");
    communicationSpi.setLocalPort(48100);
    communicationSpi.setSlowClientQueueLimit(1000);
    igniteConfiguration.setCommunicationSpi(communicationSpi);
    igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration());
    return igniteConfiguration;
}
```

Can anyone help me to make code change for creating a successful client-server connecion.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are moving from localhost deployment, you need to do the following changes:

```
 TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
 ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("192.168.33.44:47500..47509"));
```

Most likely, the server configurations need to be changed as well.

Comment: Btw, I'd suggest you try it removing the #setLocalAddress lines.